# Allow multiple users to interact with a single running instance of an executable

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop-services

We have a Windows 10 machine running an inhouse update schedule (updateSchedule.exe) which runs multiple update processes which gather data and load to a database. Scheduled processes (update1.exe, update2.exe...) are triggered by the scheduler and can also be run ad-hoc by the support team via the scheduler. The machine has a single login, service.svc, and currently all executables are run under this username.

The single login is an issue as the system can only be maintained by sharing service.svc login details between the support team who then rdp to the machine. We need the support team to be able to login to the machine using their own credentials and use the scheduler without multiple instances of the scheduler running. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The proper architecture in such cases is to have one service and then GUI controller application which runs new instance for each logged on user. These GUI apps can communicate with the service via UDP, registry keys, files or something like that, but there must be some developer tutorials for this.